# A link in a space task only works on the first click

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, google-chat

When viewing tasks in the Tasks tab of a Google Chat Space, if a task contains a hyperlink, the hyperlink only opens on the first click. If you click again, nothing happens.

Viewing another channel and returning to the original channel, then opening the Tasks tab allows you to click one more time.

Comment: [tag:google-spaces] should not be used on new questions as it corresponds to a retired web application. (See the tag excerpt).

Comment: @Rubén Should I have used google chat instead?  Spaces appear to be very active as part of google chat as a professional user.

Comment: If the "app" is Google Chat, yes, the tag to be used should be [tag:google-chat] instead. In the case of [tag:google-spaces] it has a tag excerpt that says "DO NOT USE...". It is worth noting that Google does not reserve names used on retired apps / features, actually, they use some names multiple times simultaneously, i.e., currently, they use "Google Workspace" as the name of the suite of managed services and also as the name of a Google Bard extension, so it's not strange that they use "Spaces" in Google Chat.

Comment: I used app inside quotes as strictly Google Chat is cross-platform, having an Web app, a Progressive Web App, an Android app, and iPhone and iPad app, and also it has a widget embedded in Gmail. I don't think that we should create a tag for each of them.... some general questions about Google Chat and Google Chat Spaces might be asked here, but questions that are specific to apps that are not web apps are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Chrome's built-in popup blocker

Open **https://mail.google.com/chat** in Chrome, click the **padlock** in the address bar > **Site Settings** > Set **Pop-ups and redirects** to **Allow**

This also fixes the Windows Client for Google Chat.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the "Windows Client" for Google Chat is a [Progressive Web App](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9658361).